# What does it mean of "Package 'networkx' requires a different Python: 3.6.13 not in '>=3.6'"

Tags: python, pip

I want to install package networkx 2.5.1
but the message tell me

```
ERROR: Package 'networkx' requires a different Python: 3.6.13 not in '>=3.6'
```

very strange

I am using python 3.6.13

Because I am using the company's system so I can't upgrade the python, I can only adjust the package I am installed

Comment: Can you provide the exact command and pip version you are using, as well as an other output beside that one error line?

Comment: Could it be that it requires a Python version that is '<3.6', i.e. less than 3.6?

Comment: Reminder, Python 3.6 has been end of life for almost 2 years: https://endoflife.date/python and should'nt be used anymore

Comment: @Brian61354270 Hi, just see your message I hope I could show you the message, right now I am very busy on some other project, I may be able to give you that info on weekend